# Speeding up the extraction of data from nested JSON contained in DataFrame column

Tags: json, pandas, performance, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe with a column containing nested JSON data

```
_p_final_fromPICKLE['label'].iloc[2]
```

```
'{"params": [{"X": 1500}, {"Y": 0.087}, {"Z": 0}, {"T": 0}]}'
```

I would like to populate new columns which contain directly the data (`X`,`Y`,`Z` and `T` in this case).

The best I could come up with at the moment is

```
     _p_final_fromPICKLE['Z']=_p_final_fromPICKLE['label'].apply(lambda x: utils.merge_dicts(*json.loads(x)["params"])['Z'] )
```

where

```
def merge_dicts(*dict_args):
    """
    Given any number of dicts, shallow copy and merge into a new dict,
    precedence goes to key value pairs in latter dicts.
    """
    result = {}
    for dictionary in dict_args:
        result.update(dictionary)
    return result
```

Creating the column `Z` takes 90 seconds to process 13M rows. In my opinion this is too slow, be cause I can make simple operations between columns in a fraction of a second. I think the function I defined is not the major cause because just turning the column in a JSON take 78 seconds

```
_p_final_fromPICKLE['params']=_p_final_fromPICKLE['label'].apply(lambda x:  json.loads(x)["params"]  )
```

So I was wondering if I am making this inefficient in some way. I do not see any way around from using `json.loads` because I have a JSON string in the `label` and I need to convert it into a dictionary to use the data. This `json.loads` seems to be the slow part. Maybe is due to how I am calling it. I see people [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39640936/parsing-a-dictionary-in-a-pandas-dataframe-cell-into-new-row-cells-new-columns) uses `assign` instead of `apply` but I have not managed to find a simple call that uses apply for my nested case.

Any suggestion on how to make this run faster?

Comment: IIUC, `pd.json_normalize(_p_final_fromPICKLE['label'],record_path=['params'])` the reason it takes 90s for 13m rows is due to apply which is a row level operation as opposed to set based. How much memory is this consuming? because 13m rows in 90s is quite good for an apply statement imo.

Comment: How do I check the memory usage? Are you asking for the result of .info() ?

Comment: The code you wrote assumes 'label' is already JSON, whereas it is a string in my case, that is why I was passing it by `json.loads`. For this reason it gives an error `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: What would be the *set* operation to use  in alternative to `apply`?

Comment: try using `literal_eval` `from ast import literal_eval` then `pd.json_normalize(df['j'].map(literal_eval),record_path=['params'])` `df['j']` is your json column here

Comment: this runs ok, but I stopped it after 12 minutes. It seems it had filled up memory (I have 64 Gb) and went largely into swap

Comment: well you're evaluating strings as objects so the memory usage will pileup with each iteration, another option would be to save the json as a pure json file and read it line by line and let python handle the memory allocation. `Dask` or `Pyspark` maybe better for such a large dataframe.